# Why Apache Ode cannot start on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bpel, eclipse-kepler, apache-ode

Anybody knows why Apache Ode server (which is installed over eclipse kepler) still showing the state "Starting" and never start Please ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I added tomcat-juli.jar to apache ode server to fix it, go to the launch configuration, classpath and add the external jar it's located in Tomcat's folder/bin

Comment: Thank you, saved my day. Was having the same issue on Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)

Comment: Where should i place juli-jar ? please describe a certain path